# Microsoft Modular Computing Device - Prior Art Request

Tags: prior-art-request, prior-art, microsoft, modular, lenovo

Microsoft has submitted an application for a patent to the blatantly obvious idea of designing a computer that consists of independently upgradeable modules - an idea as old as the IBM PC itself only this time the modules are wrapped in a sleek, drool-proof housing and interlocked using magnets rather than sockets.

The application can be found [here](http://appft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PG01&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/srchnum.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=20160041582.PGNR.) and as I understand it the filing date for the application is January 5th 2015.

I hereby request the assistance of the community in debunking the 20 claims covered in this patent and would suggest as a point of reference the [Industry Standard Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Standard_Architecture) or alternatively the [Lenovo Thinkpad Stack](http://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-thinkpad-stack/), which was revealed to the world on January 4th 2015 or possibly [this IndieGoGo concept called the ICE xPC](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ice-xpc-a-modular-computer-as-small-as-your-phone#/), which failed to receive funding on February 7th 2014.

Here is the first of the twenty(!) claims in the patent:

> A computing device comprising: a display modular component including a
>   housing, a display device physically and communicatively coupled to
>   the housing via a hinge, and one or more display hardware elements
>   disposed within the housing and configured to output a display for
>   display the display device; and a computing modular component
>   including a housing that is physically and communicatively coupled to
>   the display modular component, a processing system disposed within the
>   housing, and memory disposed within the housing, the processing system
>   configured to execute instructions stored by the processing system to
>   generate a user interface for display by the display device of the
>   display modular component, the processing system and the memory being
>   swappable within the housing of the computing modular component.

Here is a picture from the application to help people grasp the concept:
[image: Illustration from Microsoft's Patent Application]

Answer (score 1):

Going way back in time, there's also things like 
http://www.storiesofapple.net/the-jonathan-computer.html